# $.getJSON is not working

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working with jQuery `$.getJSON()` but it's showing an error message "Undefined" after alert 7.

```
$('#searchbtn').click(function () {
    alert('hi');
    var kwd_name = $('#txtSearchFor').val();

    var url = "http://serviceidb.woo.gy/service/coresearch/?keyword=man";
    alert(url);

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        alert('7');
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.each(data, function (index, d) {
            alert(d.imageid);
        });
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* assign handler */
        alert(errorThrown.responseText);
        $('#img_loading').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: When I looked at this service to see if CORS headers were set, I got an error. Check at what happens in the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: how to enable cross domain request?

Comment: The correct URL is `http://serviceidb.woo.gy/service/coresearch?keyword=man` and the server does seem to accept cross domain requests.

Comment: Are you managing the server or not ? If so, look at http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL is `http://serviceidb.woo.gy/service/coresearch?keyword=man` (remove the `/` before the `?`).

But you're doing a cross-domain request.

As the server doesn't set the relevant [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents your JS code to read the response.

Read http://enable-cors.org/ to see how you can parameterize the server to allow cross domain requests.